# Positive derivative on [0,1] implies a continuous derivative on [0,1]

Tags: derivatives, continuity

If a real-valued function F defined on [0,1] is differentiable with positive derivative f everywhere on [0,1], can we conclude that f is continuous?

Comment: Every differentiable function is continuous

Comment: Maybe Leslie wants to say $f'$ is continuous.

Comment: @LandonCarter f is the derivative of F, somehow I missed that

Comment: Hi, yes, I have in mind F' = f.  I understand that a differentiable function F can have a derivative f that is discontinuous, but all such examples seem to involve the derivative having a value of zero. If I assume that f>0, does that imply that f is continuous?

Answer (score 2):

Take first on $[0,1]$,  $F_1(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$if $x\not =0$, and $F_1(0)=0$. Show that $F_1$ has a derivative $f_1$ : $f_1(0)=0$ and $f_1(x)=2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)$ for $x\not =0$. Clearly $f_1$ is not continuous at $0$. We have $|f_1(x)|\leq 3$ for all $x$. Take now $F(x)=4x+F_1(x)$, for example.

Comment: Dear Kelenner, Can you construct a similar example in which the derivative f1 is positive everywhere on [0,1]?

Comment: Oh, I see now that you offer exactly that with F(x)=4x+F1(x). Thank you very much.  Sincerely, Leslie